# apostrophe generating SQL error

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a form to collect user data, including address and write them in a Mysql DB.
In the user table, `Street` is a `Varchar (255)`.
Everything works fine, unless in the name street there's an apostrophe, in this case I have 
the following SQL warning:

For example, if in the `Street` name I put "Francesco D'assisi 24"

`Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'assisi 24'`,

Any idea how to avoid it?

Comment: It`s called sql injection use prepared statements.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Pass the variables via a stored procedure parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Need to escape data: use function mysql_real_escape_string (or analogs in other libraries), or using PDO and parameters.

For example:

```
$data = <<<TXT
Francesco D'assisi 24
TXT;

$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
mysql_query("INSET INTO table VALUES ('$data')") or die mysql_error();
```